# Copy elements of an old array of pointers into new array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, element, delete-operator

I need some assistance with a C++ project. What I have to do is remove the given element from an array of pointers. The technique taught to me is to create a new array with one less element and copy everything from the old array into the new one except for the specified element. After that I have to point the old array towards the new one.

Here's some code of what I have already:

I'm working with custom structs by the way...

```
Data **values = null;    // values is initialized in my insert function so it is
                         //   populated
int count;               // this keeps track of values' length



bool remove(Data * x) {
    Data **newArray = new Data *[count - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        while (x != values[i]) {
            newArray[i] = values[i];
        }
        count -= 1;
        return true;
    }
    values = newArray;

    return false;
}
```

So far the insert function works and outputs the populated array, but when I run remove all it does is make the array smaller, but doesn't remove the desired element. I'm using the 0th element every time as a control.

This is the output I've been getting:

```
count=3 values=[5,6,7]            // initial insertion of 5, 6, 7
five is a member of collection? 0
count=3 values=[5,6]              // removal of 0th element aka 5, but doesn't work
five is a member of collection? 0
count=4 values=[5,6,5]            // re-insertion of 0th element (which is stored in
five is a member of collection? 0 // my v0 variable)
```

Could anyone nudge me in the right direction towards completing this?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `std::vector`? PS show actual code, considering the `remove` here will not ever reach `values = newArray`. Even if `count` is `0`, the `new` will fail and throw `std::bad_array_new_length` since the size must be *positive*.

Comment: If you continue with using arrays instead of `std::vector`, then I suggest you use e.g. [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) for the copying.

Comment: Oh yeah I figured people would suggest a vector, but this is for a class. I don't want anyone to do it for me, but rather a little assistance along the lines of array usage.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code is leaking memory like no good! Next you only copy the first element and not even that if the first element happens to be the one you want to remove. Also, when you return from your function, you haven't changed your internal state at all. You definitely want to do something along the lines of

```
Data** it = std::find(values, values + count, x);
if (it != values + count) {
     std::copy(it + 1, values + count, it);
     --count;
     return true;
}
return false;
```

That said, if anybody taught you to implement something like `std::vector<T>` involving reallocations on every operation, it is time to change schools! Memory allocations are relatively expensive and you want to avoid them. That is, when implementing something like a `std::vector<T>` you, indeed, want to implement it like a `std::vector<T>`! That is you keep an internal buffer of potentially more element than there are and remember how many elements you are using. When inserting a new element, you only allocate a new array if there is no space in the current array (not doing so would easily result in quadratic complexity even when always adding elements at the end). When removing an element, you just move all the trailing objects one up and remember that there is one less object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool remove(Data * x)
{
    bool found = false;

    // See if x is in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (x != values[i]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Only need to create the array if the item to be removed is present
    Data **newArray = new Data *[count - 1];

    // Copy the content to the new array
    int newIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (x != values[i])
            newArray[newIndex++] = values[i];
    }

    // Now change the pointers.
    delete[] values;
    count--;
    values = newArray;
    return true;
}
```

Note that there's an underlying assumption that if `x` is present in the array then it's there only once! The code will not work for multiple occurrences, that's left to you, seeing as how this is a school exercise.

Comment: I actually seen a similar algorithm in another post. I tried using the if statement, but that didn't work. I'll try using the "newIndex" variable to see if that makes a difference. Thanks to you and everyone else for the posts.

Comment: What do you know? The addition of that variable "newIndex" actually made a difference and allows my function to compile perfectly. I'm just thinking to myself "how would I know to do that." I do feel that there is another way to organize this so it'll work just the same. Anyway, thanks again for the help. I don't want to come off as looking for shortcuts, but I just needed an extra boost.